# PHP XML encoding regex

Tags: php, xml, regex, urlencode

I need to find a way to urlencode the values within xml tags but keeping the tags intact using PHP.
Maybe it's possible using an regular expression checking for begin tags and end tags with no tags within the element.
Or it might be better to look for data between `>` and `</` without one of either within the data.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Should become:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book>
          <author>Gambardella%2C+Matthew</author>
          <title>XML+Developer%27s+Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An+in-depth+look+at+creating+applications+with+XML.</description>
       </book>
       <book>
          <author>Ralls%2C+Kim</author>
          <title>Midnight+Rain</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
          <description>A+former+architect+battles+corporate+zombies%2C+an+evil+sorceress%2C+and+her+own+childhood+to+become+queen+of+the+world.</description>
       </book>
    </catalog>
```

**EDIT**
In the end i changed the process, eliminating this problem.

Accepted the answer since i'd probably do the trick for other people

Comment: Can you explain why you need to urlencode these textnode values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do with DOMDocument / DOMXPath.  You can just query for all non-empty text nodes and update them with urlencoded text.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//text()[normalize-space()]') as $textNode) {
    $textNode->parentNode->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode(
        urlencode($textNode->nodeValue)), $textNode);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this at work tomorrow and accept this answer if it solved the problem.